# Accessing SpSite from a Thread or ThreadPool

Tags: spsite, multithreading

I have a couple of question regarding developing multithreading webparts in SharePoint. First, let me explain the idea. I have a page with 5-7 different webparts. These webparts are constructed all in the same way, which means:

a) the retrieve some data from some SPLists

b) transform that data to xml

c) execute xslt transformation to generate html

d) output html content in the RenderContents method

This process requires approximately 500ms for a single webpart.

Now my idea is to do some performance tuning using threads. 
All the process described before could be executed by a thread in the best case in an early method of the execution pipe (ex. OnLoad) or in the worst case in the OnPreRender method.
In the RenderContents method I could in the worst case wait for the thread to finish (of course here I would implement some timeout logic).

Q1) Using this technique should increase the performance of the page, right?

My assumption: 
I have 5 webparts on the page and one webpart takes 500ms

Before: the execution time would be 5*500ms = 2500ms.
Afterwards: Max(wp1, wp2, wp3, wp4, wp5) which in my case would be  500ms.

Now, my first question:

Q2) Do I am right? If not, why?

Now let’s speak more detail about the implementation. Which technique should I use?

a) Create an new Thread and then call `Thread.join()`

b) use ThreadPool

c) Or call `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` in the `OnPreRender`

At this point I have a few other questions:

Q3) Since, I am using `SPSite` and I was reading that this Object is based on COM can I use `ThreadPool` or `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`? In some blog I was reading that ThreadPool does not support COM object, because of the Apartment mode (MTA vs STA). Moreover I think that `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` is also using ThreadPool.

Q4) Which kind of implementation/architecture would you advise me?

Q5) If I would use `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` in the `OnPreRender` method do I am sure that in the method RenderContents is only called when all tasks are finished?

I tried the implementation with Threads, but it seems not working. As soon as I am trying to access the SpSite I am getting following exception:

> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException
>   comEx) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetTokenOfCurrentUser(Boolean
>   bWindowsMode, String bstrLogin, String bstrUserKey, String bstrRoles,
>   UInt32 ulRoleCount) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.InitUserToken(SPRequest request) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPSiteConstructor(SPFarm farm, Guid
>   applicationId, Guid contentDatabaseId, Guid siteId, Guid
>   siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone zone, Uri requestUri, String
>   serverRelativeUrl, Boolean hostHeaderIsSiteName, SPUserToken
>   userToken) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri
>   requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)

I tried the implementation with `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` but I am getting following exception:

> Attempted to make calls on more than one thread in single threaded
>   mode. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010102
>   (RPC_E_ATTEMPTED_MULTITHREAD)) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetIPAddr(String bstrIPAddr)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
>   site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean
>   bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)

How can I implement such an architecture?

Comment: This is quite the complex question for a first post.

Comment: Hallo Mike,
I think it is a interesting question and it would be also useful for other developers. I think the idea is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't answer all your questions, I am not good in Threads and Threadpools. But what I could suggest you, if you want a really asynchronous load of the five webparts, use javascript ajax calls of the listdata.svc service.

This way you could retrieve all your data simultaneously and after that even use jQuery to manipulate the DOM and render the output how you like. You could even use [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to decouple the data manipulation and UI part.

Just a thought...

Comment: Hallo Norbert,
Thanks for you answer. Yes, the approach you are proposing could be a possible solution, which I will keep in mind. For the moment I would prefer to implement multithreading, because it should require less effort.

Kind regards